# How can I access graphics_toolkit qt on Octave 4.4.1?

Tags: debian, octave, debian-buster

Under Debian Buster, I have just installed octave 4.4.1 (4.4.1-2+b1), but the qt (OpenGL) graphics toolkit is not avalibale:

```
octave:2> name=graphics_toolkit()
name = gnuplot
octave:3> available_graphics_toolkits
ans =
{
  [1,1] = gnuplot
}

octave:1> octave_config_info().QT_LIBS
warning: octave_config_info is obsolete and will be removed from a future version of Octave, please use __have_feature__ or __octave_config_info__  instead.
warning: called from
octave_config_info at line 43 column 5
ans = -lQt5Network -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5Help -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lqscintilla2_qt5
```

Reading the upgrade info I can find no mention of qt being removed.  Should I attempt to compile octave from sources?  If so can anyone point me to a list or required packages?

Comment: try `octave --gui` assuming is built with gui interface.

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-4.4.html : "The octave command no longer starts the GUI by default.  Most users
    starting Octave from a shell were expecting the command line
    interface, and desktop launchers already required the `--force-gui'
    option.  With this change, desktop launchers should be modified to
    use the new option `--gui'."

Comment: if this doesn't help, can you please add the output of `octave_config_info().QT_LIBS`

Comment: @Andy My question is not about the GUI, but about what graphics package is used for plots, sorry about the confusion.  I have added the output you requested to my original question.

Comment: @ClintonWinant Yes, I can confirm this in the octave 4.4.1-2+b1 package for Debian, this looks like a build error and should be reported as a bug against the Debian package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debian Octave package 4.4.1-2+b1 appears to have been built incorrectly. This has already been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/916979) and will be fixed soon.

Specifically, Octave's configure script tests whether the system header files `GL/gl.h`, `GL/glu.h`, and `GL/glext.h` exist and can be compiled in order for Octave to be built with OpenGL support. Here is an extract of what a typical configure run looks like:

```
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for GL/glu.h... yes
checking for GL/glext.h... yes
checking for OpenGL/glext.h... no
checking for glEnable in -lGL... yes
```

Here is what shows up in the buggy [4.4.1-2+b1 package build log](https://buildd.debian.org/status/fetch.php?pkg=octave&arch=amd64&ver=4.4.1-2%2Bb1&stamp=1542719664&raw=0):

```
checking for GL/gl.h... no
checking for OpenGL/gl.h... no
configure: WARNING: OpenGL libs (GL and GLU) not found.  OpenGL graphics will be disabled.
```

I don't know specifically what was wrong with the state of the Debian archive when this build was attempted (November 20, 2018), but something appears to have temporarily made the mesa OpenGL headers and/or libraries unusable.

A rebuild of the Octave package should soon fix this temporary error.

Comment: could you point me to instruction on how to build octave from source for Debian Buster

Comment: The simplest method should be `sudo apt build-dep octave && apt-get source octave && cd octave-4.4.1 && dpkg-buildpackage`. There are many variations on that theme. You can also look at https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Compiling_from_source.